# How to create a ClickOnce project in VS 2022 and .NET 7?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, clickonce, .net-7.0

I have a c# ClickOnce project written in VS 2019 with .NET framework 4.7.2.
It uses the code described in the link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-check-for-application-updates-programmatically-using-the-clickonce-deployment-api?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp

With this code the application can check for updates programmatically.
It works just fine!

Now, I want to step up to Visual Studio 2022. I know you can still use .NET Framework 4.7.2, but there seems to be a possibility to step up also the .NET version (here: to .NET 7), through the link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/access-clickonce-deployment-properties-dotnet?view=vs-2022

Meaning, you should be able to use .NET 7 to do the job.
But, how to transform the code needed from the first link into the second one? I don't get it. Has anyone done this?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/blob/main/Documentation/dotnet-mage/ApplicationDeployment.cs

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you! I will check it out fully, even if a roughly view gives a big code mass compare to the neat code with .NET Framework concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link provided by Hans Passant was very helpful: https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/blob/main/Documentation/dotnet-mage/ApplicationDeployment.cs

Here is my understanding of these properties:

**IsNetworkDeployed**: Get the network deployment status based on environment variables.

**CurrentDeployment**: If network deployment is true, get the current deployment; otherwise, return null.

**ActivationUri**: Gets the activation URI if available.

**CurrentVersion**: Get the current version based on environment variables.

**DataDirectory**: Get the data directory path based on environment variables.

**IsFirstRun**: Get the first run status based on environment variables.

**TimeOfLastUpdateCheck**: Get the time of the last update check based on environment variables.

**UpdatedApplicationFullName**: Get the full name of the updated application based on environment variables.

**UpdatedVersion**: Get the updated version based on environment variables.

**UpdateLocation**: Gets the update location URI if available.

**LauncherVersion**: Get the launcher version based on environment variables.

These properties can be updated very easily if you understand them.

Comment: So, it might be possible to use the class in ApplicationDeployment.cs file to perform the same thing as in the function InstallUpdateSyncWithInfo() from my first link.
But how to transform 'info.UpdateAvailable' and 'ad.Update()'?

Comment: @stack123 Regarding `info.UpdateAvailable`, you can get `UpdatedVersion` and `CurrentVersion`, and perform update operations when `UpdatedVersion>CurrentVersion`. But regarding ad.Update(), you need to manually write the update program yourself. The first choice is to download, then install, and finally restart. If you find it troublesome you can also use [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows)

Comment: @stack123 If it helps you can accept it so that it can help more people. If it does not work for you, please let me know

Comment: Thank you! I think I got the picture now. You need to do the Update yourself, which I hardly can. So, I accept this as the answer of the actual situation.
Myself, I pause this step and wait for a future clarifying SW solution.